# Finding a to-do app to track a particular set of daily tasks given to the team

Tags: team-management, pm-software, tasks

We are a small team of developers. We have created a product in text messaging field. Now we have hired few guys for increasing seo of our product website. We have created a list of tasks (approximately 20) which seo guys will need to do everday. Seo guys will tell following things about each task everyday-

1. How much time they spent on task?
2. Breif description of task which they did
3. A special parameter only belonging to a particular task (e.g. Parameter "How many backlinks they added" for task "Add backlinks" )

We are looking for a todo app , which can help us accomplish something similar to this. Also we should be able to see the reports to track the performance of a particular employee or a particular task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two items can be closed by any task tracker, which has feature of time tracking: Redmine (open source), JIRA (commercial), Kaiten (commercial), etc. See comparison of time-tracking software [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_time-tracking_software).

About item #3 -- you can try to configure so-called **custom field** in a time-tracker. For example, in Redmine you can add free text or numeric custom field to Task and log there any parameter you want. If set of the tasks is very stable, you can even create a different type of ticket for every task and configure specific customer fields for it.

Comment: Also we want these tasks to be recurring. Team should see these as new tasks everyday. Also in reports all recurring tasks should be linked to main task and we should be able to see that how many hours were spent on a particular task for a particular date range. Will Redmine or other task trackers provide this type of functionality ?

Comment: Redmine out of the box doesn't have recurring tasks. But it has huge number of plugins, so try looking. Othe things you request are presented. I'm not aware of other time tracking soft.